# Wrangler build failed "Could not resolve "events"

Tags: node.js, twilio, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, wrangler

What i did:

Created the worker on the web ui and initialized locally with `wrangler init --from-dash`

I installed twilio with `npm i twilio` ,

This is the code im trying to run (index.js)

```
export default {
  
  async fetch(request, ctx) {
  const accountSid = "<>";
  const authToken = "<>";
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages
        .create({
          from: 'whatsapp:<>',
          body: 'Hello there finally!',
          to: 'whatsapp:<>'
        });
      return new Response("test");
    },
};
```

when I run npm start, i get the following errors

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "events"

    node_modules/agent-base/dist/src/index.js:5:25:
      5 │ const events_1 = require("events");
        ╵                          ~~~~~~~~

  The package "events" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "buffer"

    node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time/index.js:3:21:
      3 │ var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer; // browserify
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~

  The package "buffer" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "net"

    node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:15:38:
      15 │ const net_1 = __importDefault(require("net"));
         ╵                                       ~~~~~

  The package "net" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "tls"

    node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:16:38:
      16 │ const tls_1 = __importDefault(require("tls"));
         ╵                                       ~~~~~

  The package "tls" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "url"

    node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:17:38:
      17 │ const url_1 = __importDefault(require("url"));
         ╵                                       ~~~~~

  The package "url" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "assert"

    node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:18:41:
      18 │ const assert_1 = __importDefault(require("assert"));
         ╵                                          ~~~~~~~~

  The package "assert" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"

    node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:12:65:
      12 │ ...KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPrivateKey } = require('crypto')
         ╵                                                             ~~~~~~~~

  The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"

    node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:9:62:
      9 │ ... {KeyObject, createSecretKey, createPublicKey} = require("crypto");
        ╵                                                             ~~~~~~~~

  The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"

    node_modules/jwa/index.js:3:21:
      3 │ var crypto = require('crypto');
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~

  The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "util"

    node_modules/jwa/index.js:5:19:
      5 │ var util = require('util');
        ╵                    ~~~~~~

  The package "util" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "stream"

    node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js:3:21:
      3 │ var Stream = require('stream');
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~

  The package "stream" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "util"

    node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js:4:19:
      4 │ var util = require('util');
        ╵                    ~~~~~~

  The package "util" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file and make sure to prefix the module name with "node:" to enable Node.js compatibility.
```

node version - v20.11.0

npm version - 10.2.4

(installed node js using the tar from the official website)

OS - pop os 21.04

Comment: Hello, Have you find solution for that?